# Redirecting stdin of subprocess does not work with Windows / Qt

Tags: c++, windows, qt

We have a Qt (Qt 5.7) application that runs on Windows 8.1 that we want to launch from another Qt application. The parent process should communicate with the child process by reading from its `stdout` and `stderr` and writing to its `stdin`.

The child process is a Windows GUI application. In the child process, we have a class `ConsoleReader` with the following initialization code (we followed the information found [here](https://forum.qt.io/topic/56484/solved-attach-console-to-gui-application-on-windows/5)):

```
QSharedPointer<QWinEventNotifier> mNotifier;

...

AttachConsole(GetCurrentProcessId());

// Reopen the std I/O streams to redirect I/O to the console.
freopen("CON", "w", stdout);
freopen("CON", "w", stderr);
freopen("CON", "r", stdin);

mNotifier.reset(new QWinEventNotifier(GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE)));
connect(mNotifier.data(), &QWinEventNotifier::activated,
        this, &ConsoleReader::onData);
```

and then the slot:

```
void ConsoleReader::onData()
{
    QTextStream input(stdin, QIODevice::ReadOnly);

    const QString line = input.readLine();
    // Process line here
}
```

In the parent process, we do:

```
QProcess process;

process.setProcessChannelMode(QProcess::MergedChannels);
process.start(executablePath, arguments);
process.waitForStarted();
```

We then read from the child process's `stdout` / `stderr` with

```
QTextStream inputStream(&process);
... inputStream.readLine();
```

and write to the child process's `stdin` with

```
const QByteArray bytesToWrite = ...;
process.write(bytesToWrite);
```

Reading from the subprocess works.
On the other hand, when the parent process tries to write, write succeeds on the parent, but no data is received by the child.

Notice that the same solution works on Linux. On Linux the initialization code in the `ConsoleReader` is

```
QSharedPointer<QSocketNotifier> mNotifier;

mNotifier.reset(new QSocketNotifier(STDIN_FILENO, QSocketNotifier::Read));
connect(mNotifier.data(), &QSocketNotifier::activated,
this, &ConsoleReader::onData);
```

and the rest of the code is the same.

So, what could be the problem when trying to write to the child process's `stdin` on Windows?

Comment: You can drop the calls to `AttachConsole` and to `freopen`, they're silently failing and don't do what you want anyway - the `CON` device represents the console window, not standard input/output.   As for the standard input, are you sure the parent process is sending whatever end-of-line character readLine() is expecting?

Comment: Thanks for the hints. I have left the `AttachConsole` and `freopen` out and now it seems to work. Somehow I find the information in the page I have linked a bit misleading. I now have to do some thorough testing.

Comment: That discussion really was about letting a GUI program create and use a console.  You're trying to read and write to the standard handles provided by the parent, completely different scenario.